# Testing angularJS ui-router resolve functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, jasmine, angular-ui-router

I am testing angular 1.3 (coffeescript) with ui-router 0.2.15 and jasmine 1.3

I have my module set up as follows

```
angular.module('myModule', [
  'ui.router'
])

.config ($stateProvider) ->

  $stateProvider.state 'dashboard.settings.account',
    url:            '/account'
    controller:     'SettingsAccountController'
    templateUrl:    'dashboard/settings/account/account.tpl.html'
    resolve:
      phones: (Resolver) ->
        return Resolver.resolvePhones()
```

The question is: how to test resolve function within the state? I've mocked the resolve service in controller so other tests work fine, but I don't know how to get to this particular function.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to inject your `service` which is being resolved before loading the `controller` .

```
var phones;
    beforeEach(inject(function(Resolver){
        phones =  Resolver.resolvePhones()
    }));
```

now inject this `phones` in you controller .

Comment: The test coverage wouldn't catch this as a test of that specific function, but the service itselt.
It would have to come from $state.current.resolve.phones which is empty.

Comment: Your code doesn't test resolve function. There is no error. I need to find a way to test a function within .state object, not controller

Comment: you can spy on state and manually call state.go and check whether phones is available or not

Comment: I don't have any $stateProviders defined while tests are running, so I can't call state.go because it has no where to go.

Comment: you can inject in your beforeEach

Comment: Inject what? If I inject anything into controller it won't do the job as it will only test the resolver itself, not the function that is being called in $stateProvider

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of CoffeeScript syntax, but this is how I test my simple route configuration in regular JS.

```
    describe('ui-router config', function() {

      var $rootScope, $state, $injector, myServiceMock, state = 'dashboard.settings.account';

      beforeEach(function() {

        module('myModule', function($provide) {
          $provide.value('Resolver', myServiceMock = {});
        });

        inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$state_, _$injector_, $templateCache) {
          $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
          $state = _$state_;
          $injector = _$injector_;
          $templateCache.put('template.html', '');//empty html content 
        })
      });

      it('should respond to URL', function() {
        expect($state.href(state)).toEqual('#/state');
      });

      it('should resolve data', function() {
        myServiceMock.resolvePhones= jasmine.createSpy('resolvePhones').andReturn('findAll');
        // for jasmine version greater than 2.0, replace "andReturn" with "and.returnValue"

        $state.go(state);
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect($state.current.name).toBe(state);

        // Call invoke to inject dependencies and run function
        expect($injector.invoke($state.current.resolve.data)).toBe('findAll');
      });
    });
```

Its my first time testing route configuration as well. This works fine if your service does not return promise. I'm facing issues when the service method returns promise. Let me know if you can get it working with service returning promise.